# Getting 'Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0' after upgrading firebase crashlytics library to 18.4.0

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Upgraded firebase-crashlytics dependency in the project from 15.0.2 to 18.4.0 after getting below warning from Google Play Support.

> SDK: Fabric (Firebase Crashlytics)- ID Bridging
> io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric (consider upgrading to version
> com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0)

In order to implement this, first removed the Fabric dependency from the project and upgraded the firebase-crashlytics version. After that got below error:

> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0.

Any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: Does it tell the same for any other version? I use v18.6.1 and it works fine.

Comment: Yes it is showing same for other versions too @Jaffar